# sub except the first pattern that match

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I know how to sub in awk, gred, sed but don't know how to sub except the first match. I searched in doc but can't find the right command to do it.
i have a simple file like this:

```
tongtha AL_Vcs abcdef
tongtha AL_Vcs abcdef
tongtha AL_Vcs abcdef

tuanngu AL_Ptime HEO
tuanngu AL_Ptime HEO

vuau AL_Ptime E2x
vuau AL_verdi_b E2x
vuau AL_TShell EU2HL
```

and this is my desire

```
tongtha AL_Vcs abcdef
        AL_Vcs abcdef
        AL_Vcs abcdef

tuanngu AL_Ptime HEO
        AL_Ptime HEO

vuau AL_Ptime E2x
     AL_verdi_b E2x
     AL_TShell EU2HL
```

and it would better if even i can sub it in $2 not only $1 like this:

```
tongtha AL_Vcs abcdef
               abcdef
               abcdef

tuanngu AL_Ptime HEO
                 HEO

vuau AL_Ptime E2x
     AL_verdi_b E2x
     AL_TShell EU2HL
```

Comment: In the second example, the sub-in-for-$2 is done for the first two paragraphs but not the third.  Is that a typo?

Comment: i want to keep the $3 or i will count it later

Comment: I was referring to second case in which you wanted to substitute in for `$2`.  In the first two stanzas, `$2` has been removed.  In the third stanza, it is kept.  In particular,  `AL_verdi_b` and `AL_TShell` are both `$2` and they are kept.

Comment: i think $2 and $3 should use array to sort it
, minimize pattern similar and count it. But the problem is i have to much user, if i use array and count it minimize and count the whole file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Replacing the first column with spaces but not on the first match

```
$ awk '{save=$1} $1==last{gsub(/./," ",$1)} {last=save} 1' file
tongtha AL_Vcs abcdef
        AL_Vcs abcdef
        AL_Vcs abcdef

tuanngu AL_Ptime HEO
        AL_Ptime HEO

vuau AL_Ptime E2x
     AL_verdi_b E2x
     AL_TShell EU2HL
```

#### How it works

- `save=$1`

  This saves the value of the first column in variable `save`.
- `$1==last{gsub(/./," ",$1)}`

  If the first column is the same as the variable `last`, then we replace the first column with an equal number of blanks.
- `last=save`

  This updates the variable `last` with the value of that the first column had before any substitutions.
- `1`

  This is awk's cryptic shorthand for print-the-line.

#### Replacing the first two columns but not on the first match

To do the same for the first two columns:

```
$ awk '{save=$1} $1==last{gsub(/./," ",$1); gsub(/./," ",$2)} {last=save} 1' file
tongtha AL_Vcs abcdef
               abcdef
               abcdef

tuanngu AL_Ptime HEO
                 HEO

vuau AL_Ptime E2x
                E2x
               EU2HL
```

Comment: oh dear, you saved my life. Thank a lot John. It took me almost this morning to find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;N;/^(\S+\s+\S+\s+)(.*\n)\1/{:b;s//\1\n\2\1\n/;h;s/\n.*//;s/./ /g;H;g;s/\n(.*\n).*\n(.*)\n(.*)$/\1\3\2/;ba};/^(\S+\s+)(.*\n)\1/bb;$b;/\n\s*$/b;h;s/\n[^\n]*$//p;g;s/.*\n//;ba' file
```

The sed script prints groups of lines at a time. The script first tests for first and second fields repeating and then uses a generic solution to replace those fields with spaces. If the first test fails, the script then tries to match just the first fields and if successful uses the same solution as  above.